# What is the best way to demonstrate a linear relationship between two dependent variables?

Tags: regression

I'm trying to find the correlation between two variables, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about this so thought I'd ask it here.

Say we have a game. The aim of the game is to score more points than your opponent. The person with the most points wins.

There's an obvious dependence / correlation here between `most_points in a game` / `winning_score` and `wins`, because those are the rules of the game.

I want to model this simple correlation but I'm not sure what's the right way to go about it.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you want to model? It seems completely deterministic: if you score $11$ points and I score $12$, I win, but if I score $10$, you win.

Comment: I want to model the correlation between a win and the highest score in a match. Because the rules of the game mean highest score = win, the correlation should be 1 shouldn't it?

Comment: It's football Sunday in the US, and if my team scores more points than the opponent yet loses, I will be upset. (Yes, the correlation should be $1$. Outscoring the opponent and winning the game are synonyms.)

Comment: So what would be the best way to model this? Let's say I choose another metric: most disposals. What would be the most appropriate model I could use on both to get a correlation?

Comment: The model is that if you score more points, you win, and if you won, you scored more points.

Answer (score 1):

The model is that if you score more points, you win, and if you won, you scored more points. Given the rules of your game, those are synonyms.

Most games behave that way, though you could introduce more complex rules. For instance, the card game Hearts wants to keep scores low, but if you get a sufficiently high score, you wind up winning. I remember calling this “shooting the moon”.